# How do I download PyPy?

Tags: download, pypy

I run **Windows 10 64 bit**.

I haven't tried downloading PyPy because I didn't find any tutorials on YouTube.

I have also went to the official PyPy website but it is for Python 3.6

Do I need to have python 3.6 downloaded too?

Also tell the steps to download PyPy

Edit: I am having problems in installing modules too. It gives a ***GINORMOUS*** error saying I need wheel, and some compilers like G77, GNU, Visual C++, etc.

Comment: Anything to everything in python is a pip installation, until and unless you try a parallel package manager like Anaconda

Comment: Do we use pip in PyPy too?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I dont think you need python 3.6 installed,
If you have already downloaded pypy from the website, extract the file by right-clicking on it and run the .exe file. Then run pypy and you shouldn't have any problems from there on.
Hope my advice is useful.

Comment: OK, I'll try downloading PyPy, but also, how do I download package like pandas and Numpy? I am using tkinter GUI and I if I have surfed the net right, PyPy supports tkinter. What about .py to .exe ?

Comment: From what I can find, I believe you would open comand prompt and type in the command 'pypy -m pip install [module name]' so for numpy it would be 'pypy -m pip install numpy' andTkinter should work respectively

Comment: .py to .exe, I will have to look up on

Comment: Can I use pyinstaller or any other commands like cx_freeze or there is any other command for PyPy? Please reply quick!

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use pyinstaller with it according to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025366/pypy-and-pyinstaller.) If the files are saved with the extension [.py] it may be possible as I've found other sources that say they've been successful. So, I would try pyinstaller and if it works, great. If not try looking at this page [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470800/compile-pypy-to-exe) as you may understand more about the article than I do. As for cx_freeze, if I search it up, all i get it the second page I linked.

Comment: Any other commands for .Py to .Exe? BTW I just downloaded PyPy, when I am trying to install a module, it says pypy is not recognised as a command, is it environment variables stuff?

Comment: When I imported tkinter, it didn't gave error. But when I created a Tk() object, it gave an error. Why? It says that tcl wasn't installed properly.

Comment: BTW the website didn't have the link to 64 bit Windows download. Is this causing the errors?

Comment: Looking at [this](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/windows.html), PyPy only supports translating on 32 bit windows, even on 64 bit. So I don't think that is your issue.

Comment: And as for Tkinter, I know when I use IDLE with standard python, I would do `import Tkinter as Tk`. I don't know how you would do that in PyPy. This [link](https://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-tkinter-and-idle-with-pypy.html) shows people have been having similar errors to yours and problems in general.

Comment: Ok, you might need to install pip to install the modules according to [PyPy's website](https://www.pypy.org/download.html) and hopefully that will solve a few of your module issues. As for .py to .exe, without using pyinstaller which isn't supported by PyPy yet, I'm afraid I can't help you with it.

Comment: And how do I install pip for pypy?

Comment: I think it is working as I searched the pypy website for it. So first I did ```pypy3 -m ensurepip``` then I did this ```pypy3 -mpip install numpy ``` and it looks like it is downloading numpy. I'll let you know if any error pops out. BTW thanks 

Comment: Ah man, a big big big error came saying that Microsoft visual C++ is required

Comment: Well can I copy the pandas and numpy from the Python which I already installed?

Comment: Microsoft visual c++ is usually installed with anything that needs it. [Download Link. ] (https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)You should just be able to download it and run it with no problems related to it.

Comment: If pip is working then you can just use the pip commands to install the modules I believe. If that's not what you meant can you rephrase/elaborate

Comment: Do I need to download Visual Studio? If yes, then it is very large software, my net won't let me download it. Isn't there another way for downloading modules?

Comment: I'm not talking about visual studio as in the IDE. I'm talking about Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable which you would download from the link I commented earlier. The download is only 14MB.

Comment: O_o OK but the link directed me to Visual Studio

Comment: Is it vc_redist?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is

Comment: Then I think I have already downloaded vc_redist x86. It is in ```C:\\``` directory. Even then the error occurred. Do I have to put it in the directory of ```pypy```?

Comment: You can try that, however I did some searching and it looks like it means thee microsoft [build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/), which would make more sense

Comment: Ok I'll try that. And as always, any error and you'll be informed